# appache poi dependency issue

Tags: java, excel, spring, apache-poi

hi i am trying to read excel sheet using appche poi, i have added following dependency

```
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>
```

my Spring Version is

```
        <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

i have written following code

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @PostMapping("/dump-data-from-excel")
    ResponseEntity<String> dumpDatafromExcel(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipart) {

        try {

            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(multipart.getInputStream());

            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            System.out.println(sheet.getRow(0).getCell(1).getCellType());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;

    }
}
```

when i hit this method i am trying to print data type from my excel sheet , instead of data type is is returning

numbers

```
output: 1
```

Comment: In that ancient version of Apache POI (version 3.7) [Cell.getCellType](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_7/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.java?view=markup#l124) had returned `int`. But why using that ancient version of Apache POI? Current version is 5.2.3.

Comment: i tried XSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type
 XSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type
 XSSFSheet cannot be resolved to a type now giving this error

Comment: You should try solving this issue then, instead downgrading to a decades old version.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it’s working correctly, unless the first cell on the first sheet is not a string.

The getCellType returns a org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType enum. The value for STRING is 1. See the source code [here](http://www.java2s.com/example/java-src/pkg/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/celltype-135b2.html).

Try the enum.name(), ie

```
System.out.println(sheet.getRow(0).getCell(1).getCellType().name());
```

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are facing an issue with the data type of the cell value returned by Apache POI while reading data from an Excel sheet. The value returned is 1, which is the numeric value of the cell, instead of the data type.

To resolve this issue, you can use the DataFormatter class provided by Apache POI. The DataFormatter class can be used to format the value of a cell based on its data type.

Here's an example of how you can use the DataFormatter class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@PostMapping("/dump-data-from-excel")
ResponseEntity<String> dumpDatafromExcel(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipart) {

    try {

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(multipart.getInputStream());

        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
        String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(0).getCell(1));
        System.out.println(cellValue);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return null;

}
```

In the above example, we have created an instance of DataFormatter and used it to format the cell value. The formatCellValue() method of the DataFormatter class takes a Cell object as a parameter and returns the formatted value of the cell.

By using the DataFormatter class, you should be able to retrieve the correct data type of the cell value.